# objective c find out my location?

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I'm trying to get my location in simulator. A couple of time it worked but... Now I always get 0.000000 as my location. There is code that I used:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
NSLog(@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude);
```

After running app I change in the simulator Debug -> Location -> Custom Location... Does somebody can explain why does it stop working?

Comment: Where are your delegate methods????

Answer (score 1):

This will never work, except by accident:

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
```

When you call `startUpdatingLocation` you get *delegate* messages (assuming you have a location manager delegate, which you should, always) — in particular, `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`. *That* is where you receive information about your location.

Comment: See my discussion and examples here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch35.html#_location

Comment: ok, i see it. now how to get only lat and long from "locations" NSArray in didUpdateLocations method

Comment: Well, think about it. What _is_ `locations` in `didUpdateLocations`? It's an array of CLLocation. So how do you get one CLLocation from an array of CLLocation? How do you get latitude and longitude from one CLLocation?

Comment: object of CLLocation class have a property "coordinate" of CLLocationCoordinate2D type which is a struct. So, you can access to that data, via: "cllocationclassobject.coordinate.latitude" & "cllocationclassobject.coordinate.longitude"